# how to update libc on debian squeeze?

Tags: updates, glibc

I want to install Arachni scanner on my debian squeeze box. But it has problem with glibc version. It need glibc 2.15 but what is installed on my debian is 2.11 .

How can I update my libc from 2.11 to 2.15 ?

Answer (score 2):

you can use the Arachni build scripts to build a package for your system:

```
wget -O - https://raw.github.com/Arachni/build-scripts/master/bootstrap.sh | bash
```

You will need to have a few dev dependencies available like gcc, g++ and more but the build scripts will check for env sanity and let you know if you're missing anything.

Answer (score 0):

The `libc` library is used by virtually every program on your system, and as such it is no simple task to merely update it to a newer version. Doing so will likely break everything else on your system. The best recommendation would be to find a version of Arachni which was compiled against the libc version already on your system, preferably one which is specifically packaged for Squeeze (a quick Google search, unfortunately, doesn't seem to yield any packages for Debian). Alternatively, you could download [the source](http://www.arachni-scanner.com/developement/code-repository/) and build it for your system against the right library versions. Of course, you will need to install the `-dev` packages for the required libraries.

EDIT: This is the unfortunate thing about providing binary packages for Linux applications. Different distributions provide different versions of libraries, and you really should be using packages compiled against those specific versions (or compatible versions). This normally isn't a problem because most applications build against most of the popular distributions and provide RPMs and Debs for them. Installing from raw tarballs is usually problematic, even without library issues. This really should the software developers responsibility to provide suitable binary packages for their users.